# C# FtpWebRequest with SSL to Ubuntu VSFTPD

Tags: c#, ssl, ftpwebrequest, ftps, vsftpd

I have spent hours trying to get the .NET FtpWebRequest library to communicate with my Ubuntu 16.04 FTP server using vsftpd over SSL.

No matter what I try, I always end up with the exception "A call to SSPI failed. The message received was unexpected or badly formatted."

I have tried generating client and server certificates, installing them in windows, loading them with the X509 class in .NET, toggling various client and server side options. No matter what I do, it's always the same error. I believe this has something to do with my certificate not being verified by an authority. Here are my basic questions:

1) Can .NET just ACCEPT a suspicious certificate?! Installing it 30 different ways seems to have no affect?

2) What does "a call to SSPI failed" really mean? I've read conflicting answers. I have no problem connecting with TLS/SSL via FileZilla, but .NET 4.5 just won't have it.

3) Can someone give the minimum amount of steps to have a Windows 7 client using the .NET framework connect to a Linux server using vsftpd over SSL? I strongly believe the problem lies in my Windows/.NET settings since FileZilla on my Windows machine has no problem connecting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share your c# code?

Comment: Try connecting to the ftps server listed [here](http://test.rebex.net/). You can bypass server certificate validation by adding the following code `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);` and corresponding method `public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }`

Comment: I've used the delegate { return true; } for the ServerCertificateValidationCallback member. At this point, I believe the calls are failing due to the hostname of the certificate not matching the requested server according to the client. I haven't taken the time to investigate this as of yet.

Comment: I've ended up using SFTP through my SSH library, which has no problem using a dev SSL certificate. I also got MySQL and .NET to communicate using a dev SSL certificate. And I'll reiterate that FileZilla happily prompts me to accept the certificate when I connect. It's really just this .NET FTP library that wants nothing to do with SSL certs that can't be validated by a RCA.

Comment: Good research. You've got me curious now, so I'll try setting up an IIS FTPS server using a dev cert and see if I can make it work with the .NET FTP client.

Answer (score -1):

Insert the line below in your vsftpd.conf:

```
ssl_ciphers=AES128-SHA
```